# Having users of two apps play together using play services

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have two apps on the market (Lite and full version) and I am planning to introduce multi-player using google game services to both. But I want the users of both apps to be able to play together (room creation and automatching joining).

Is this possible or is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely possible.

In your game services tab on your developer account, just ensure that both (or more) apps are using the same Game.  (so that the are both listed under the "linked apps" section of the Game.)

Any linked app then shares whatever resources are available for that app (leaderboards for ios/android). So, in the case of multi-player for Android they will all be using this o-auth to establish connections.  If you DO want to have separate room connection types for the Pro vs Lite, you can use the room setup flags to ensure that only the chosen app can connect to others with the same setup (for that room builder).

Comment: Awesome ! Perfect. never occured to me! Thank you